# No detailed tiles outside my state (google maps android api v2)

Tags: android, google-maps

My Android google maps api v2 application is loading tiles only for my state (Colorado, US). If I move the map area outside of this state, I get only very fuzzy high-level tiles, with no actual map detail.

- Local maps work fine, throughout the state of Colorado
- Utah or Kansas or France or Spain maps show very, very high-level fuzzy, unusable features.

Overall the whole app is working fine. Is there some kind of permission on the api key or something that I have to do?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#getting_the_google_maps_android_api_v2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that I had fat-fingered the application name in the credentials section of the Google API console. So the key I was using was not actually authorized. Google seems to let you use a key "a little bit" but not fully. Strange!

I did go back and test - it wasn't just a glitch. When I switch it back to the wrong application name, it has this behavior again. When I switch it to the right application name, it works perfectly. (You do have to kill the app in between; it seems to get authorized at launch or something.)